# Apache URL rewriting with a maintenance page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm not really used to Apache rewrite module, so I need a little help ^^

I currently have this :

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|html|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]`

It redirects all requests to `index.php` if they're not pointing to an existing file with the extension listed above.

Now, I want to add a rule that says :

- if the file maintenance.html exists at root, redirects to it for any request
- otherwise send the request to index.php (or return the file if it's an existing and allowed file)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say you just have to add the exception before the usual rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond /maintenance.html -f
RewriteRule ^ maintenance.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpe?g|png|css|html|xml)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

And a general note. You should *always* prefer to place such rules in the actual http servers host configuration. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, are hard to debug and they *really* slow the server down, often without reason. They are only offered for situations where you do *not* have access to the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting providers) or if an application needs to write its own rewrite rules (which is a security nightmare anyway).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know for the slow down from the htaccess files. Anyway, I don't have access to the server configuration :s

Comment: The reason for the slow down is a pretty simple one: the server has to check each of the file system folders up to all objects referenced by a request (include files!) for such files, read them (again and again, since they may have changed) interpret them and act accordingly. Compared to that a single pass through at startup time for rules placed in the host configuration appears like technical heaven...

Comment: Yep but... Isn't Apache verifying for the existence of such files anyway?

Comment: Only if they are enabled (configuration setting). If not enabled they are not checked at all.

Comment: Hum, ok, I see. Really interesting to know! It could be useful for the future with my clients ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tested your rewrite and it does not work. I probably forgot to say that the .htaccess (besides my index.php) does not necessarily at the root of the website but can be in a subdirectory (for a dev version of the website, per example). I tried many things, but didn't figure out how to make it work. Moreover, do you think `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` is really needed?

Comment: (sorry for the time I took to test this, but I had to dev the application first ^^)

Comment: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/maintenance.html -f` solved this